Error 401 Unauthorized error when using LDAP authentication in Apache Druid
I have this sample LDAP in Apache Directory LDAP server
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Organization
dc: example

dn: ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users

dn: ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: uid=admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
cn: Admin User
sn: User
uid: admin
mail: admin@example.com
userPassword: admin123
title: Administrator
description: Admin role user

dn: uid=internal_user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
cn: Internal User
sn: User
uid: internal_user
mail: internal_user@example.com
userPassword: internalpass
title: Internal Employee
description: Internal user role

dn: cn=admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: admins
member: uid=admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=internal,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: internal
member: uid=internal_user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com

Here is my LDAP config inside "auto/_common/common.runtime.properties" file:
druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["ldap"]

druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.type=basic
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.enableCacheNotifications=true

druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.type=ldap
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.url=ldap://localhost:10389
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.bindUser=uid=admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.bindPassword=admin123
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.baseDn=dc=example,dc=com
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.userSearch=(&(mail=%s)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))
druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.credentialsValidator.userAttribute=mail

druid.auth.authenticator.ldap.authorizerName=ldapauth

druid.escalator.type=basic
druid.escalator.internalClientUsername=uid=internal_user,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
druid.escalator.internalClientPassword=internalpass
druid.escalator.authorizerName=ldapauth

druid.auth.authorizers=["ldapauth"]

druid.auth.authorizer.ldapauth.type=basic
druid.auth.authorizer.ldapauth.initialAdminUser=internal@example.com
druid.auth.authorizer.ldapauth.initialAdminRole=admin
druid.auth.authorizer.ldapauth.roleProvider.type=ldap

I am getting this error when starting Druid
2024-09-14T05:57:52,825 WARN [main] org.apache.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils - Retrying (1 of 9) in 774ms.
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Input does not start with Smile format header (first byte = 0x3c) and parser has REQUIRE_HEADER enabled: can not parse
 at [Source: (byte[])"<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 401 Unauthorized</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/druid-ext/basic-security/authentication/db/ldap/cachedSerializedUserMap</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>401</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Unauthorized</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>default</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
"; line: -1, column: 0]

